# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - There is no missing )!

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm at a complete loss for what's wrong with this code.

Here is what I've done up until the error:

```
$(function () {

    for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
        $("#_Q1_Q" + i + "_Q2_C").change(callbackFactory(i));
        $("#_Q1_Q" + i + "_Q2_C").change(function(n){
            return function(){
                toBus(n);
                console.log(n);
            };
        }(i));
        toBus(i);
    };

    $("#_Q0_C0").change(function(){
        noTraveller();
        console.log("Stage 1");
    };); // <--- This is where the error occurs
```

There is more to the code but all the brackets are 100% in order. In fact if I comment out the section of code below (where the error occurs) then my script will run exactly as intended, barring the commented out function.

```
$("#_Q0_C0").change(function(){
    noTraveller();
    console.log("Stage 1");
};);
```

Comment: `};);` should be `});` - no `;` after `}`

Comment: Oh all the people jumping on this question to point out a typo...

Comment: Universal truth: If the compiler tells you that there's a syntax error... then there is a syntax error.

Comment: Use `jsHint` in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Tomalak: Universal corollary: when a programmer makes a syntax error, they'll usually assume they're perfect and whoever wrote the compiler was an idiot.

Comment: the question itself you have answer. This sounds you didn't tried to debug your code. Console will show with the line of your error. use console to check these kind of javascript errors

Comment: @Scironic: Comments like you just edited in are more suited for the comment section, here. Everyone misses a `;` once in a while. Learn from it and move on ;)

Comment: Argument lists can't end in a semicolon `;`. A sentence can end with a semicolon. So, as many point to you, only last semicolon on your example is correct, as it finishes the sentence. The other one is incorrect because it is inside the argument list.

Comment: @moderators, this is not a typo, a typo involves an error typing. The wrong semicolon here, seems intentional. Must be informed to the OP and to everyone with the same mistake

Comment: @LuisSiquot: there are plenty of questions (& answers) about "*SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list*"

Comment: @Cerbrus, so this question is a duplicate, but not a typo

Comment: @LuisSiquot: Still, no reason to re-open it.

Comment: There are plenty of questions which start the same but none of them seemed to have the exact problem, the solutions never worked. The semi-colon was intentional as I was being overly safe with my syntax.

Comment: @Scironic: But as you probably noticed, that resulted in a `;` in the `change` call: `.change(  function(){<stuff>}  ;  );`

Comment: I have noticed now. And I've finally gone and bought a JavaScript reference so I can actually learn how all the basics work in more depth. Apparently online learning wasn't enough for me. Although I do agree, there is no need to re-open this for such a small mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the superfluous `;`

```
 $("#_Q0_C0").change(function () {
     noTraveller();
     console.log("Stage 1");
 };);
  ^
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
$("#_Q0_C0").change(function(){
    noTraveller();
    console.log("Stage 1");
};);
 ^ //remove that semicolon
```

Should be:

```
$("#_Q0_C0").change(function(){
    noTraveller();
    console.log("Stage 1");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One semicolon too many.

Remove the first semi-colon in the line after after the console.log.

It should look like this:

```
$("#_Q0_C0").change(function(){
  noTraveller();
  console.log("Stage 1");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to like this

```
$("#_Q0_C0").change(function(){
        noTraveller();
        console.log("Stage 1");
    }); // <--- Note here: remove `;`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {

for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
    $("#_Q1_Q" + i + "_Q2_C").change(callbackFactory(i));
    $("#_Q1_Q" + i + "_Q2_C").change(function(n){
        return function(){
            toBus(n);
            console.log(n);
        };
    }(i));
    toBus(i);
};
})
$("#_Q0_C0").change(function(){
    noTraveller();
    console.log("Stage 1");
});
```

function is not closed properly,check your console for errors

Comment: At least mention what has changed. Not everyone will notice the missing `;`. (Aside from that fact 4 other answers mention it)

Comment: }) before this $("#_Q0_C0").change(function(){

Comment: ... in the answer itself.

Comment: ..... @KarthickKumarGanesh: that wouldn't be the right place.....! Did you just copy someone else's answer...!?

Comment: no , i not copied ,that function is also not closed properly and semicolon also be the issue

Comment: Sorry, I misread your response (OP said there was more code, so I assumed it was closed later and this was part of the function - closing it there would cause problems; I would think).

Comment: Closing it would cause problems as there's a hundred or so more lines of code to be ran on page ready. But I appreciate the input!